# Use COUNTA but only if two columns are not empty?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet to keep track of the number of events that we have completed. At the top I have running totals using COUNTA(). For the number of "completed" events, I am trying to use COUNTA() but only if a select range of cells in each row are not empty.

Here is how I have it set up:
[Layout of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUJkD.png)

I have the "Planned" column as a simple COUNTA() because as long as there is a title in a row I consider it being planned: [Planned COUNTA()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dB4f.png)

How can I do a COUNTA() for "Complete" that only counts if the Evaluation, Amount spent, Req. submitted, and Updated budget rows are also full? I don't need to validate anything in terms of what it equals, I just need to check that all of them have something entered into them.

Thank you for any help! I'm sure it's probably a simply formula but I can't seem to find other posts to help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS with criteria as `"<>"` This equates to *not blank*.

```
=countifs(a:a, "<>", e:e, "<>", g:g, "<>", h:h, "<>")-1
```

The `-1` is for the header labels in row 7.

That should work with your current data layout. It should be a small matter to change the full column ranges to something tighter if you need to start using G:H in rows above 8.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.